# Commit code to a specific branch _after_ writing all the code (git)?

Tags: git, workflow, agile

Say I'm on the `development` branch and I've just been refactoring for an hour...  I had no plan going in, but an hour later I happen to have done a lot of work on some specific feature, say work on the `routing` part of an MVC.  Is there a way to commit that code to a dedicated `routing` branch that may or may not currently exist in the project, without committing it to the `development` branch first?  I want it to be as if, for the past hour, I was writing code in the `routing` branch.

The problem with checking out a specific branch *during a hacking/refactoring session* is that the work you're about to do is unpredictable.  So, there's no way to know "checkout the `routing` branch" in advance.  So what I end up doing is just keeping everything in a `development` branch.  But the problem with that one massive branch is it's hard to work on multiple features at once without breaking everything.  It seems like the ideal, then, would be to [`cat >>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29) the past hour of refactoring, which happened to be all routing, into a new/existing `routing` branch.  Then for the next hour, I may do half routing, half database, so throw that into `routing` and `database`, retrospectively.

Is that possible?  What workflows do you use to make this easier?

Comment: Not a solutian to your problem, but I think it's better if you know beforehand what you are going to code. Note, that with git, you can create as many branches on the fly as you want and then commit to those when you need to.

Answer (score 3):

The key is to commit often. That's one of the nice features with Git, that you can keep local commits and squash them together when you think you're done.
In that way, you can easily work with the refactoring for a while and just checkout a new branch for the new features.

In your case, you can stage only the "refactoring" changes ("git add" on those) and make a commit to the development branch. After that (with your routing-changes still unstaged and not commited), you can checkout to a routing branch and commit your unstaged routing-changes there.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest bet is to commit whatever you've done to `develop`, do `git checkout -b routing` leaving you with 2 branches (develop and routing) both at the same point

then `git checkout develop && git reset --hard origin/develop` to put develop back where it was before you started hacking.

Comment: `git reset --hard` should always be taken with a grain of salt. It will remove all uncommitted changes from the work tree (if you happen to not have committed everything). Also, this assumes that `develop` was recently pushed to the `origin` repository (`origin/develop` does not have to exist). `git checkout -b routing && git checkout develop` seems unnecessary complex, why not `git branch routing`? That way you will stay on branch `develop` and don't have to switch again.

Comment: I always forget about the existance of `git branch` to create new branches. I'm so stuck in my `co -b` workflow.

WRT to `reset` yes you have to be careful, but I think that goes without saying.

Answer (score 1):

A quick flow :

```
git stash
git checkout routing
git stash pop
```

Otherwise, you can always commit your changes to a local branch :

```
git checkout -b wip #create branch wip
git add <some files>
git commit
git add <some files>
git commit
etc...
```

and once you've commited, you can jump to another branch and `cherry-pick` any intermediate commit you want, or `checkout` specific files or directories :

```
git checkout routing
git cherry-pick 1bf56de #<- sha1 of one of your commits from your wip branch
git checkout 2cc54aa -- path/to/myFile #<- INDEX gets updated with this version of myFile
git checkout 2cc54aa -- whole/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check out the branch you want and use the -m flag:

```
git checkout -m routing
```

Then commit your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Branching in git is cheap, so branch **early** and **often**.

Before starting any coding, branch the 'development' into a temporary local branch.
Work there, as MackeiaN said, commit often too, you can squash later.
Remember you can change your history locally as much as you like before pushing to a public server.
If you feel unsafe about history editing, you can branch again before doing it (if commits are referenced by tags or branches, you can't lose them, you have the reflog anyways)

When you end your coding session, merge, rebase or rename this temporary local branch to wherever it needs to go.

If you don't feel confident with all git's basic operations, i recommend you reading [the "Pro Git" book](http://progit.org/book) specially its ["Git Branching" chapter](http://progit.org/book/ch3-0.html).